# How to add dynamically function with the jquery plugin contextmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the contextmenu jquery plugin : http://ignitersworld.com/lab/contextMenu.html

My initial menu object is defined like this :

```
var menu = [{name: 'EN',title: 'EN_title'},{name: 'FR',title: 'FR_title'}];
$(".MyClass").contextMenu(menu);
```

It works normally.
Now, I want to add functions dynamically on each item. 
For example, if I click on EN, I want to trace EN_title. If I click on FR, I want to trace FR_title.

The new menu object should be like that :

```
var menu = [
{
    name: 'EN',
    title: 'EN_title',
    fun: function () {
        console.log(this.title);
    }
},
{
    name: 'FR',
    title: 'FR_title',
    fun: function () {
        console.log(this.title);
    }
}
];
```

How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var menu = [{
                name: 'EN',
                title: 'EN_title',
                fun: function () {
                    console.log(menu[0].title)
                }
            }, {
                name: 'FR',
                title: 'FR_title',
                fun: function () {
                    console.log(menu[1].title)
                }
            }
            }];
 
//Calling context menu
 $('.testButton').contextMenu(menu);
```

Comment: I'm agree with you but I want to add dynamically the functions to the initial array like menu[0].fun = function(){console.log(menu[0].title)} and menu[1].fun = function(){console.log(menu[0].title)}

Comment: oh yeah.. you can add dynamically. you might have to reinitialize the buttun. ie. run  _$('.testButton').contextMenu(menu);_ after the change

Comment: finally I've found a solution : I create an object and push in a menu array. thank for your help

Comment: there is no need to create a new item in the menu array. You can add directly add the 'fun' object to the menu item.